# Mel Spectrogram Implementation in Python

Tags: python, signal-processing, spectrogram, mfcc, windowing

First of all, I am a beginner and I'm trying to replicate the process of obtaining Mel Spectrogram from an audio file. For the first step, I want to try windowing my signal using Hanning or Hamming window with 25 ms window length and 10 ms window step and then do Fourier Transform to each window. I'm quite lost in this step, so I'm asking for your help.

Here's the code that I tried

```
def stft(signal, windowSize, windowStep):

    # Frame number estimation from a signal
    n_frames = 1 + int((len(signal)-windowSize)/windowStep)

    # Initialize empty matrix
    stft_matrix = np.zeros((n_frames, int(windowSize/2)+1),dtype=np.float32)

    # Count STFT loop, keep only the nyquist freqs
    for i in range(n_frames):
        start = i * windowStep
        end = start + windowSize
        frame = signal[start:end]*np.hanning(windowSize)
        frame_fft = np.fft.fft(frame)[:int(windowSize/2)+1]
        stft_matrix[i, :] = np.abs(frame_fft)
    return stft_matrix    

wav_name = 'Q4.wav'
x, sr = librosa.load(wav_name, sr=None)

window_size = 0.025  # 25 ms
window_step = 0.010  # 10 ms
stft_matrix = stft(x, int(window_size * sr), int(window_step * sr))

# Plot the magnitude spectrum of the desired frame
plt.plot(stft_matrix[0, :])
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.show()

stft_matrix[10,:].shape
```

I was expecting if I change the window size, the magnitude of the frequency should stay the same, but when I change it the magnitude changes, the frequency range changes, but the plot kind of look the same. I'm sorry if I'm asking an idiotic question, but am I doing this wrong or not? Please help me.

[This is when I set the window_size to int(window_size * sr))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtwHU.png)

[This is when I randomly set the window_size to 2048](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi6eI.png)

Once again I'm sorry if this seems idiotic, but I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: when you change window size, you change data that is input to each consecutive FFT. Larger the window, better frequency resolution and worse time resolution.

Comment: you can also change size of the fft by appedning zeros at the beginning/end of the window, in such a case you increase sampling of the frequency spectrum. There is `nfft` parameter in fft that does that for you

Comment: I see. One more problem I forgot the mention is when I'm using Librosa's melspectrogram function and I try to modify the window_size, it seems like it's stretching the audio. When I set it to 800, the spectrogram's time axis reaches 45 s, when the original audio is only 30 s long. But when I left it at default, the time axis is correct. Can you help me on this? Thank you for your answer before!

Comment: Ask another question, add code, images what is expected what is happenin etc. Minimal reproducible example